# Need to access JavaFX from a eclipse plug-in code

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am trying to use JavaFX package in a Java 8 code from eclipse plug-in. I was able to compile it, but at run-time the plug-in is not able get JavaFX class loaded. 
Looks like, OSGi Plug-in is not able load classes from "[JAVA]\jre\lib\ext\" directory, but able to load classes from "[JAVA]\jre\lib\". Any pointers how to resolve the issue is highly appreciated.

** I understand there is a way off e(fx)clipse or copying jfxrt.jar to the plug-in class-path will resolve the issue, but I wanted to know why plug-in is not able to load from /ext/ path of the JRE.

Comment: See [_"Java vs OSGi Class Loading"_ blog post by Sathya Bandara](https://medium.com/@technospace/java-vs-osgi-class-loading-17a1ad4cc2a5)

Comment: I understand, but as I don't have JavaFX as plug-in, I cannot access JavaFX through "Import-Package" in manifest.mf

Comment: In your `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` is `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment` set and if yes, to which value?

Comment: The value for 'Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment' is **JavaSE-1.8** in MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: This means only the packages that are specified by the `JavaSE-1.8` profile (see [here property `org.osgi.framework.system.packages`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.osgi/JavaSE-1.8.profile#n14)) can be accessed. For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52019047).

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It doesn't load these classes.But got the solution, as following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the following link
[Unresolved JavaFX packages in OSGi Felix Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738369/unresolved-javafx-packages-in-osgi-felix-application), we did the following steps to fix the issue.
The following are the OSGi configuration properties.

`org.osgi.framework.bundle.parent` - Specifies which class loader is used for boot delegation. Possible values are: boot for the boot class loader, app for the application class loader, ext for the extension class loader, and framework for the framework's class loader. The default is boot.

`org.osgi.framework.system.packages` - Specifies a comma-delimited list of packages that should be exported via the System Bundle from the framework class loader. The framework will set this to a reasonable default. If the value is specified, it replaces any default value.

So by adding

```
-Dorg.osgi.framework.bundle.parent=ext  
-Dorg.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=javafx.*
```

the VM args, it added required dependency.